# Sorry, something went wrong (Web app)

Tags: error

I had project up and running on Sharepoint. I was customizing the "web apps," I believe they were called. (I was adjusting the site's front page where project summary, documents, news feed are.) I added one app called "My Tasks," and then it crashed and gave me the following error and the troubleshoot link doesn't work. Could anyone assist me with this error?

> "Sorry, something went wrong An unexpected error has occurred.
>
> Web Parts Maintenance Page: If you have permission, you can use this
>   page to temporarily close Web Parts or remove personal settings. For
>   more information, contact your site administrator. TECHNICAL DETAILS
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. Correlation
>   ID: 4e87569d-e0d9-2000-2113-2802e7dd5939
>
> Date and Time: 1/18/2016 11:48:30 AM"

[image: sharepoint error]
[image: troubleshooting error]

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

Add this QueryString to the URL: ?Contents=1

If this is your URL: http://servername/pages/home.aspx then you will add the QueryString; http://servername/pages/home.aspx?contents=1

Answer (score 0):

Click the Web Parts Maintenance Page link and delete the My Tasks web part.  That should make the error go away.

Then use the Correlation ID from the error page to search the SharePoint logs to troubleshoot the error adding that web part caused.